# Are questions asking for confirmation of a method off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, homework-and-exercises

I have asked a question relating to how I have approached a problem. My reason for asking the question was my answers seem to be unrealistic. The question is here:

[How to calculate force on a string pinned to a spinning object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149667/)

It was put on hold reasonably soon after I asked the question. I just want to confirm if what the reason for it being put on hold was so I can better phrase the question. The reason give was:

> Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept
>   and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our
>   questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users.
>   See our meta site for more guidance on how to edit your question to
>   make it better

My question was clearly about a specific physics concept, and I've clearly found and tried to apply an equation to work through the problem (not that it's homework). I've also reduced my problem to the simplest model I could so it was useful to the broader community. So I'm not sure the given reason really applies. Clarification/advice on what changes would be appropriate would be very helpful.

Comment: Note that [check my work](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) questions are off-topic.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for the response. Does this come under the check my work policy as I'm asking if I'm applying a method correctly? I understand if it does, I just don't want to make the same mistake again!

Comment: Here's a hint, if you're asking a question and it's reasonably possible that the only answer someone could give is "Yes", then it's probably not a good question to ask here. It might be fine to ask on our chat, however. If a question can be answered that way, it means it's not asking us for a physics explanation. We like reading ourselves type, so let us explain a concept. Questions where the answer is "Yes" or "No, you need to do this instead" don't fit with our policy of explaining physical concepts

Comment: @Jim 'like reading ourselves type' I think that is brilliant. Maybe we could add 'like hearing ourselves think'. Sorry off topic - i will delete this soon.